# How can I identify memory modules in a PC so I can upgrade it?

Tags: memory

I am in the middle of moving all my clients, at the firm I work for, to Office 2007 from Office 2003.

A few of the computers only have 512 mb ram, which is not enough to run Office 2007 properly.
As you might have guessed from the amount of ram, some of the computers are a few years old. I can't find labels on them, telling me which brand and number they are.

If you know the brand and model number, there is a ton of sites that can identify what kind of ram you need to buy.

But is there a way to identify this information, when it is not displayed on the case?

Comment: Step one: kick the ass of the previous administrator for not labelling those computers. Step two, once you know the information you need, label those computers so the next administrator won't kick your ass!

Comment: Will do :) Workshop Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several tools that will pull out the RAM details.
One such tool is [**SIW** -- System Information for Windows](http://www.gtopala.com/).

However, There are tools from memory vendors ([CrucialScan.exe](http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/))
which will exactly tell you what upgrades are available for the specific system
(and even price estimates).

All you need is the tool downloaded and an Internet access on the machine
for the tool to lookup the suitable RAM modules.

Comment: Just a heads up: I ran SIW on 2 machines with completely different hardware. In both cases the DDR3 RAM is identifies as DDR2. Same problem with the other RAM identifier programs I've tried.

Comment: @John, I guess most of these tools have not yet figured out DDR3 (it does not work without `i7`, afaik). Did you try `CrucialScan`?

Comment: CPU-Z only detected 8GB, where SIW could detect Kingston as manufacturer, the model, the serial, the speed, the year and week of production, form factor, as well as the jedec profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can try **[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php)** to get some details about the memory modules.

> **CPU-Z** is a freeware that gathers information on some of the main devices of your system.
>   
> **Memory**
>
>   Frequency and timings.
>   Module(s) specification using SPD (Serial Presence Detect) : vendor, serial number, timings table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Crucial System Scanner tool**

[Crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com) has an online memory scanner that you can run, even if you do not know the manufacturer or model number of your computer. It scans your computer to find out what is already inside your system and get recommended upgrades.

[image]
<sub>(source: [crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com/images/btn_systemscanner-onblue.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Open up one of the machines, remove an existing memory module, record all details from it and google the various potential part numbers you see on it - one will turn up and should tell you what type of memory it is, then go to crucial or similar and order up some generic memory of that kind, test it, if it works then you can order more.

Answer (score 0):

The motherboard manufacturer and model number is normally printed on the board itself. Grab a flashlight and start looking.

Comment: This was downvoted but I don't understand why. Having found that most software methods are at best unreliable I believe opening the case and having a look is the best solution. +1